# Python regex not finding a number in the range of 1 to 34 as expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a number which is in the range 1 to 34 in my string but not getting the expected output. 
Code:

```
re.findall("(\d[1-34])","hi34hi30hi12")
```

Output:

```
['34','12']
```

Where is 30 here?? Or am I doing it wrong??

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: `\d[1-34]` actually matches a digit, followed by a digit that's in the range 1-3, or an "4".

Comment: The correct regex - `(([1-2][0-9]?)|(3[0-4]))`

Answer (score 1):

That regex is wrong.
As it's been said in a comment above, your regex will match a single digit `\d`, followed by a single character in the set {1,2,3,4} which is the explicit meaning of the character class you used `[1-34]`

This one matches all the 2 digit numbers from 00 to 34 :

```
re.findall("([0-2][0-9]|3[0-4])","hi34hi30hi12")
```

this expression is made of two parts : the first

```
[0-2][0-9]
```

matches two characters, the first be a 0, a 1 or a 2 and the second a numerical digit; the second part is alternative the the first match (using the `|` operator)

```
3[0-4]
```

and matches a 3 followed by a 0, a 1, a 2, a 3 or a 4.

That expression, thus, as required, matches all 2 digit numbers from 00 to 34.

Comment: To really help OP, please explain why his regex is incorrect.

Comment: The question asked for the range 1 to 34, not 00 to 34.

Answer (score 0):

`\d[1-34]` actually matches a digit, followed by a digit that's in the range 1-3, or an "4".

- "34" was matched because `\d` matched 3, and then the 4 inside the character class matched the 4.
- "12" was matched because, again, `\d\` matched 1, and then 2 was matched because it's in the range 1-3.

As mentioned in the comments, a better solution would be matching all 2-digit numbers and verify the range manually:

```
>>> re.findall("(\d\d)","hi34hi30hi12")
['34', '30', '12']
```

Now iterate over the list and verify the range.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can do my search then??

Comment: Do you mind explaining how the question marks work?

Comment: Use `r"(?<![\d.])\d{2}(?![\d.])"` to match all 2-digit numbers, cast to int and check if the number is between the specified range.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't match 29

Comment: @A.Rama correct. Will fix.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why not using only `\d{2}`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I love complicating things :) `\d{2}` will match any sequence of 2 digits. `(?<![\d.])\d{2}(?![\d.])` will match integers that are surrounded with non-digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess I got a downvote for over simplifying :)

Comment: I don't agree, the question was about the regex and not a programmatic solution. Your `\d\d\` regex is not a correct solution for the question.

Comment: @A.Rama: Let me remark that a regex is also a "programmatic" solution. One should know how to use it in the specific code environment.

Comment: @A.Rama OP already got a regex for that. I suggested a better solution (at least for me). I hate using regex for all tasks in the word. For god sake, matching a range shouldn't be validated using a regex.

Comment: Why using a regex when you just can parse the string yourself? That's because, when parsing large amount of data, a regex can be quite fast and powerful and expressive. Programmatic solutions or post-analysis are sometimes needed because regexs are not always able to express every possible 'word' that you want to match, but it's definitely not the case here.